# How to make a route filter in Laravel 4 ?

Tags: laravel-4

I want to make a route filter in Laravel 4 for my application.

Details:

- I want to allow this route filter for **only**
- user->type = 'Distributor'
- distributor->type = 'OEM'

I know for sure that `{{ Auth::user()->distributor()->first()->type }}` will return **OEM**

Here is the code in my **filters.php**

```
Route::filter('distributor', function() 
{
        if (Auth::user()->distributor()->first()->type !== "OEM" )

        {
            if (Request::ajax())
            {
                return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
            }

        }

        else return View::make('errors.404_auth');
});
```

I got an error :

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you tried to access the relation between the user and the distributor, but you have not check to the if the user with that particular type is actually exist.

My suggestion will be

Add `if (Auth::user()->type == " You user type in string "){` on top of your first if statement.

See the code for detail. I hope this help !

```
Route::filter('oem', function()
{

    if (Auth::user()->type == " You user type in string "){

        if (Auth::user()->distributor()->first()->type == "OEM")
        {
            if (Request::ajax())
            {
                return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
            }

        }

        else return View::make('errors.404_auth');

    }
});
```